# What operation should I use to organize the data in the correct way, i believe it might be subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im trying to get the number departments in a building and how many room there are in those departments. On the photo you can see on the right it says "total apartments with 1 room, with 2 rooms and so on but i can't figure out how to get that result, also when i use group by on the number of rooms or i add the number of rooms. the number of departments get separated (which they do in kind of the right form i just don't know how to display it)"

On the left you can see the result i'm getting right now and on the right the expected result

[image]

This is how it looks before i group by

[image]

```
select e.edi_nombre_edificio "NOMBRE EDIFICIO",
       count(d.id_edificio) "TOTAL DEPTOS"
       --d.total_dormitorios


from edificio e join departamento d on
e.id_edificio=d.id_edificio
group by e.edi_nombre_edificio --,d.total_dormitorios
order by e.edi_nombre_edificio;
```

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected output. It should be in the form of text but not as an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Case Expression`

```
SELECT e.edi_nombre_edificio "NOMBRE EDIFICIO",
       SUM(d.id_edificio) "TOTAL DEPTOS",
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.total_dormitorios << Match your condition for 1 room>> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Total Deptos 1 Dormitorios",
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.total_dormitorios << Match your condition for 2 room>> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Total Deptos 2 Dormitorios",
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.total_dormitorios << Match your condition for 3 room>> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Total Deptos 3 Dormitorios",
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.total_dormitorios << Match your condition for 4 room>> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Total Deptos 4 Dormitorios",
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.total_dormitorios << Match your condition for 5 room>> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Total Deptos 5 Dormitorios"
FROM edificio e join departamento d ON e.id_edificio=d.id_edificio
GROUP BY e.edi_nombre_edificio
ORDER BY e.edi_nombre_edificio;
```

And the result will be

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was what i was trying to do but didn't know you could use 'case' like that. Is this the most efficient method btw? thanks a lot for your answer i know my question post wasn't the best.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your data structure but the following should definitely work for you which is using `PIVOT` and there is no need of `group by` as it will be taken care by `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT
            E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO, --"NOMBRE EDIFICIO",
            --D.ID_EDIFICIO 
            D.TOTAL_DORMITORIOS,
            COUNT(1) OVER(
                PARTITION BY E.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO
            ) AS TOTAL
        FROM
            EDIFICIO E
            JOIN DEPARTAMENTO D ON E.ID_EDIFICIO = D.ID_EDIFICIO
    ) PIVOT (
        COUNT ( 1 )
        FOR TOTAL_DORMITORIOS
        IN ( 1 AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO", 
             2 AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 2 DORMITORIO", 
             3 AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 3 DORMITORIO", 
             4 AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 4 DORMITORIO", 
             5 AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 5 DORMITORIO" )
    )
```

Cheers!!